# C++ MySql connection handling in codeblocks

Tags: c++, mysql, codeblocks

I'm doing an extention of Autocomplete in Open Office.
It requires to connect to a database to fetch words.
I used codeblocks to write the codes,but it makes problems with the my sql header file.
How can I configure codeblocks to include mysql header files?
Is there any alternative?
What are the steps with terminal code?

Comment: Does " it makes problems with the my sql header file" mean it can't find a header file when you try to compile?

Comment: yes it gives that error

Comment: Can you post the code where you try to include this troublesome header file? #include ... what exactly

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
#include <some_sql_header.h>
```

in your code, you need to tell cthe compiler where this is on disk.

You can either use the /I switch (for include path) or go into the code::blocks IDE and add the path to `project build | search directories | compiler` tba.